# Android App - Internal storage save Not showing up

Tags: android, save

***[Edited again, because I think I might be starting to understand.]***

My old question is below.

However, I think my question has now boiled down to this.

Is **Internal Storage** in `data/data` and cannot really be accessed on your phone, unless you go through the complicated `rooting`?

Is **External Storage** in `Android/data` and will go on a connected SD card, or in the main memory if you don't have an SD card attached. The public can see this on their phones through the `File Manager`.

**--- OLD QUESTION ---**

I am saving a file twice.

When I am saving on the internal storage I am also saving a backup as well.

However, the backup save to internal storage is not showing in the file directory in File Manager. (But it is showing up in **internal** storage when I believe I am saving **EXTERNALLY**.)

I believe internal storage is located as shown below (but i am starting to doubt it - I am new to android - I am using the **Genymotion** emulator):

```
File Manager|Android|com.mysite.jon.myappname|files
```

If not where is **internal storage**?

Here is my code:

```
public void save(boolean saveLocal, boolean saveExternal, String fileContent) {
    boolean ret = true;

    // The false indicates I am saving internally (ie isExternal = false)
    if (ret && saveLocal && !saveLocalExternal(false, fileContent)) ret = false;
    // I am shutting off external save at thee moment to make the problem clear
    //if (ret && saveExternal && isExternalStorageWritable() && !saveLocalExternal(true, fileContent)) ret = false;

     return ret;
}

public boolean saveLocalExternal(boolean isExternal, String fileContent) {
    boolean ret = true;
    String filename1 = "a.txt", filename2 = "b.txt";
    File path = isExternal ? mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) : mContext.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(path, this.filename);
    FileOutputStream outputStream, outputStream2;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, filename1));
        outputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();

        if(!isExternal) {
            outputStream2 = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, filename2));
            outputStream2.write(fileContent.getBytes());
            outputStream2.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**So where is `b.txt`? Surely it should be in internal storage?**

Comment: I didn't get you totally but as per my understanding if you ever created sharedprefences in android.Those data will be stored in /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml.That Means your data is stored in Internal Storage

Comment: Thanks. I now believe `/data/data` is not really accessible to the public unless they root their phones. This is also interesting to know about `sharedpreferences`, as I will be having a hand-full of these. However, I am specifically interested in the file saves using `FileOutputStream`. From what I can tell the internal storage of these also go in `data/data`. The external storage goes in `Android/data` which Joe Public can access in their `File Manager`. (Basically I need to allow the user to have an accessible save because they can use that save on their phone or laptop in an html version.)